# Double quotations inside parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, quotations

Trying to programatically add links inside of a table.

```
$("#p"+col).append("<a href='#' id='tablep"+col+"' class='ui-link-inherit' onClick='tableSelect('p"+col+"')'></a>");
```

Note how ...'tableSelect('p"+col+"')'>... is in single quotes, but its parameters also have to be in quotes.  So when it runs, it cuts `tableSelect(` off like so and throws `p1)` or whatever number it is, elsewhere.

Here's what it looks like in the console:

```
<a id="tablep1" class="ui-link-inherit" p1')'="" onclick="tableSelect(" href="#"></a>
```

See what I mean?  Anyway, is there a way around this?

Comment: a general hint: dont use inline javascript. use the jquery bind-methods for the click-event. -> `$('tablep1').on('click',function({...});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a much cleaner way to build elements with jQuery:

```
$("#p"+col).append($("<a>", {
  href: '#',
  id: 'tablep' + col,
  "class": 'ui-link-inherit',
  click: function() { tableSelect('p' + col); }
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

`onclick` attributes are a very outdated method of attaching events. As you are using jQuery to insert the HTML, why not use that to bind your events? Try this:

```
var $a = $("<a href='#' id='tablep" + col + "' class='ui-link-inherit'></a>").click(function() {
    tableSelect(this);
});
$("#p" + col).append($a);

function tableSelect(obj) {
    // do something with the clicked object
}
```

It's also worth noting that using incremental `id` or `class` attributes is a massive pain for maintenance and will hinder future development. A better method is to use classes and DOM traversal to find the specific element required.

Comment: was using onClick because the .click() method was not firing.  New to jQuery and self teaching, so I don't know all of the work-arounds yet, thanks though!

Comment: No problem. You may want to ask another question to find out why the click event wasn't firing as using `onclick` is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery, don't build HTML via string concatenation.

```
var newAnchor = $('<a>')
    .attr('id', 'tablep' + col)
    .addClass('ui-link-inherit')
    .click(function () {
        tableSelect('p' +col);
    })
    .appendTo($("#p"+col));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Escaping_characters) quotes inside string with backslash:

```
"\"";

'\'';
```